# Understanding flyback transformer datasheet

Tags: power-supply, mains, flyback

Please see the below image of a flyback transformer I found. I see voltage/current outputs at each secondary winding. My question however is, how are these determined? I thought the output levels are dependent on primary voltage, switch frequency, duty cycle... What is the meaning of these ratings? My best guess is these outputs are based on some "typical" application example which is not in the datasheet.
[image]

Comment: You're asking a question about contents in a datasheet yet you haven't provided a link to said datasheet or have told us what device you're looking at. Can you provide this information?

Comment: Datasheet is here:https://katalog.we-online.com/ctm/datasheet/750343140.pdf Transformer is intended for a multi-output offline flyback converter.

Comment: It does seem to be oriented around an application example that references this part.  A shame the part doesn't reverse reference back to the application example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is actually based on a "typical" application, as you stated.

Searching this in WE site, these results came out:
https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/search?search=750343140

The first one implies that this transformer (750343140) is a "MID-OLTI Offline Flyback Transformer for Texas Instruments".

By clicking on the second result, we see a demoboard (TIDA-00708) description. It implements a flyback converter using the TI's UCC28881 device. On the bottom of the page the 750343140 is referred as a product.

In the demoboards datasheet we see a transformer named 750343140***R00*** (there is an extra suffix). The layout of the transformer in the pg.1 is the same as the 750343140 layout.

The key system specifications are almost exactly the same as those referred on the schematic:
[image]

In the 2nd table (pg.6) though, it states that the Fmax (Desired switching frequency) is a little higher, at 62kHz (not 52kHz as in the schematic).

To conclude, it seems that these values on the schematic refer to a specific flyback application and that they are (probably) the dc values of operation.